# apache graphx merge/combine multiple graphs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm new to Apache GraphX and I want to see if I can do graph merge/combine in graphX.
  What I want to do is say I have 2 graph as below

```
graph1:     A —1—> B —1—> C —1—> D
            |
             —1—> E —1—> F

graph2:    A —1—> B —1—> C
           |
            —1—> G
```

and I want to get merge/combine result like

```
merge result: A —2—> B —2—> C —1—> D
              |
               —1—> E —1—> F
              |
               —1—> G
```

I can do this in Neo4j embedded graphDB with Path object to compare path, accumulate edge count and join in missing path.

Is there anyway or example that can help me do the same thing in GraphX?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new graph based on a union of the vertices and edges and then use groupEdges():

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut

val verts1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1L,"A"),
    (2L,"B"),
    (3L,"C"),
    (4L,"D"),
    (5L,"E"),
    (6L,"F")))

val edges1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Edge(1L,2L,1),
    Edge(2L,3L,1),
    Edge(3L,4L,1),
    Edge(1L,5L,1),
    Edge(5L,6L,1)))

val graph1 = Graph(verts1, edges1)

val verts2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1L,"A"),
    (2L,"B"),
    (3L,"C"),
    (7L,"G")))

val edges2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Edge(1L,2L,1),
    Edge(2L,3L,1),
    Edge(1L,7L,1)))

val graph2 = Graph(verts2, edges2)

val graph: Graph[String,Int] = Graph(
    graph1.vertices.union(graph2.vertices),
    graph1.edges.union(graph2.edges)
).partitionBy(RandomVertexCut).
   groupEdges( (attr1, attr2) => attr1 + attr2 )
```

If you now look at the edges of this new graph you can see the merge results:

```
scala> graph.edges.collect
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Int]] = 
      Array(Edge(1,2,2), Edge(2,3,2), Edge(1,5,1), 
            Edge(5,6,1), Edge(1,7,1), Edge(3,4,1))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to union based on the value of vertex property, not the vertex id? Because sometimes it's hard to make the same vertex id has exactly the same property and vice versa

Comment: BTW, this answer helps solving part of my issue. But I have a more open issue posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221099/apache-graphx-merge-combine-multiple-graphs-according-to-vertex-property-of-rela. Appreciate your help